# How to make inner object in object using recursive code in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have some object type data.
Each object have same key, `children`.
`children` can have another `children`.

```
const testColumns = {
    label: '테스트 수',
    width: 320,
    children: [
        {
            label: '1-1111',
            width: 160,
            children: [
                {
                    key: 'testCnt', 
                    label: '2-3333', 
                    width: 80,
                },
                {
                    key: 'exceptionCnt', 
                    label: '2-4444',
                    width: 80,
                    children: [
                        {
                            key: 'allTestCnt', 
                            label: '3-5555', 
                            width: 80,
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'allExceptionCnt', 
                            label: '3-6666', 
                            width: 80,
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I have to make other object from `testColumns` to rearranged object, `returnColumns`.

like this.

```
let returnColumns = [];

testColumns.map((obj)=>{

    if(obj.children){

        obj.children.map((child, firstChildIndex)=>{
            returnColumns['children'] = [];
            returnColumns.push({
                property: child.key,
                    header: {
                        label: child.label,
                    },
                    props: {
                        style: {
                            width: child.width
                        }
                    });

            if(child.children){
                returnColumns[firstChildIndex]['children'] = [];
                child.children.map((secondChild, secondChildIndex)=>{
                    returnColumns[firstChildIndex]['children'].push({
                        property: secondChild.key,
                        header: {
                            label: secondChild.label,
                        },
                        props: {
                            style: {
                                width: secondChild.width
                            }
                    });
                })
            }
        });
    }
})
```

I try to make above code to recursive function. like this.

```
function recursiveIteration(object, callback) {

    for (let property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

            if (typeof object[property] == "object"){
                recursiveIteration(object[property]);
                // ...
                // ...
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how work this.

---

Above code is sample. It's not perfect.
[Here is jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cnaa97/48ns5zn5/)

---

Here is what I want result

```
const test = {
        property: undefined,
        header : {
            label: 'TEST1'
        },
        props: {
            style: {
                width: 320,
            }
        },
        children: [
            {
                property: 'test',
                header : {
                    label: 'test'
                },
                props: {
                    style: {
                        width: 160,
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                property: undefined,
                header : {
                    label: '2-4444'
                },
                props: {
                    style: {
                        width: 160,
                    }
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        property: 'allTestCnt',
                        header : {
                            label: '3-5555'
                        },
                        props: {
                            style: {
                                width: 80,
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        property: 'allExceptionCnt',
                        header : {
                            label: '3-6666'
                        },
                        props: {
                            style: {
                                width: 80,
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Don't make `returnColumns` a global variable. Create local variables, and **`return`** the value.

Comment: I added what i want return result @NinaScholz

Comment: @Bergi Yes. but that code is sample. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive callback for mapping values of the array.

```js
var testColumns = { label: '테스트 수', width: 320, children: [{ label: '1-1111', width: 160, children: [{ key: 'testCnt', label: '2-3333', width: 80, }, { key: 'exceptionCnt', label: '2-4444', width: 80, children: [{ key: 'allTestCnt', label: '3-5555', width: 80, }, { key: 'allExceptionCnt', label: '3-6666', width: 80, }, ] }] }] },
    result = [testColumns].map(function iter(o) {
        var temp = {
                property: undefined,
                header: { label: o.label },
                props: { style: { width: o.width } }
            };

        if (o.children) {
            temp.children = o.children.map(iter);
        }
        return temp;
    })[0];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Amazing! It's Really helpful. I don't know why I did not think so. I need more study... Thanks.